# Should I include the protocol for Meteor's $ROOT_URL environment variable?

Tags: http, https, meteor, environment-variables, absolute-path

`Meteor.absoluteUrl` has a `secure` option which creates a HTTPS URL, so I guess Meteor only allows either the `http` or `https` protocol. So would it be any difference to not include the protocol, and just use `//example.com/` as the `ROOT_URL` environment variable? Or it makes a difference?

Should I include the protocol for Meteor's $ROOT_URL environment variable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The implementation of [Meteor.absoluteUrl](https://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteor_absoluteurl) can be found [here](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/master/packages/meteor/url_common.js). As you can see, it modifies `ROOT_URL` (`options.rootUrl`) with `https` if `secure` is true **and** `ROOT_URL` uses the `http` protocol.

If you are hosting your site using `https` anyway, I'd recommend including it in the `ROOT_URL`, e.g. `https://app.example.org`. That's what we do and it works fine. It certainly seems easier to change an environment variable rather than modifying your code.

Note that if you don't want to specify the protocol you should set your `ROOT_URL` like `app.example.org` and not `//app.example.org` - again see the implentation.

Answer (score 0):

Above answer is no longer true. It seems Meteor has changed implementation and now ROOT_URL must be a valid URL with either http or https.
See https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/87681c8f166641c6c3e34958032a5a070aa2d11a/packages/meteor/url_server.js#L8